# Can you return a value from a main() function in Python?

Tags: python, import, return, program-entry-point

Let's say I have a utility script:

`utility.py`

```
def func1(input):
    # do stuff to input
    return stuff

def func2(input):
    # do more stuff to input
    return more_stuff

def main(argv):
    stuff = func1(argv[1])
    more_stuff = func2(argv[1])
    all_stuff = stuff + more_stuff
    # write all_stuff to stdout or file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(argv)
```

And this script is called by another rollup script, like so:

`rollup.py`

```
import utility

def main(argv):
    # assuming a list of of inputs is in argv[1]
    inputs = argv[1]
    for input in inputs:
        utility.main(['utility.py', input])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(argv)
```

Now let's say I want the rollup script to print or write to file **a combined output of all the stuff generated by each instance of utility.py**.

Is there any way to do this by **returning the output from utility.py to the rollup script?** Or does the rollup script have to read in all the output or output files that utility.py generated?

Note that I am *not* asking if this is considered best practices or if it's "allowed" in programming circles. I am aware that main is supposed to only return success or fail codes. I'm merely asking if it is **possible.**

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen` and capture `utility`'s output from `rollup`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code the `main` function is nothing more than a regular function named `main`. So if you're asking if you **can** use `return` in your `main` function, then absolutely yes. You most certainly can

Comment: If I added a `return` statement inside `utility.py`'s `main` function, could I still call `utility.py` by itself from the command line?

Comment: @RetroDad Nothing makes me think it isn't possible.

Comment: Yes you could. The return value would just be lost. If you want to actually return an error code from the script the best way is to use `sys.exit`

Comment: btw I know this is pretty obvious, but the effort of setting up a test case for that is minimal. Try it out yourself :)

Comment: @Fred Duly noted. Perhaps a better question would have been "What happens to the return value if x?", which is answered above.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You could, for instance, return a dictionary (or list, or tuple, or whatever) in `utility.main()` and then grub all the dictionaries and store them in a list in `rollup.main()`, inside the `for` loop, for further elaboration.

Your `utility.main()` is nothing else than a normal function in this case.